# Display text on a button click Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, button, ngfor

I've created three buttons with ngFor, each button has it own name which is stocked in the array: buttonData[].
buttonData also contains texts and images.
What I'm trying to achieve here is when I click on one of my buttons a text and an image appears, each button has its own text and image of course.
I can't understand why my function doesn't work since I have no error.
Here is my code:

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FeaturesService} from '../features.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-features',
  templateUrl: './features.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./features.component.css']
})
export class FeaturesComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private featuresService: FeaturesService ) { }
    title = 'Features';
    textprediction: String;
    textrebalancing: String;
    textvisualization: String;
    text = '';
    img = '';
    buttonData = [
      {
        title: 'Prediction',
        description: this.textprediction,
        img: '../../assets/prediction.png'
      },
      {
        title: 'Rebalancing',
        description: this.textrebalancing,
        img: '../../assets/rebalancing.png'
      },
      {
        title: 'Visualization',
        description: this.textvisualization,
        img: '../../assets/visualization.png'
      }
    ];

  ngOnInit() {
      this.featuresService.getFeatures().subscribe(value => {
        console.log(value);
        this.textprediction = value[1].textprediction;
      });
      this.featuresService.getFeatures().subscribe(value => {
        console.log(value);
        this.textrebalancing = value[2].textrebalancing;
      });
      this.featuresService.getFeatures().subscribe(value => {
        console.log(value);
        this.textvisualization = value[3].textvisualization;
      });
  }
  onTitleClick(i: number) {
    this.text = this.buttonData[i].description;
    this.img = this.buttonData[i].img;        
  }
}
```

**component.html**

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<tr class="btn-group" *ngFor="let button of buttonData; let i = index">
  <td>
    <button (click)="onTitleClick(i)">
    {{button.title}}
    </button> 
  </td>
</tr>
```

The three variables textprediction, textrebalancing and textvisualization is some text that I get from my json file.
I can't understand why it works when I declare my function this way:

```
  onTitleClick() {
    this.text = this.textprediction;
  }
```

But when I ask my function to go and get it in my array it doesnt work.

Comment: In template where you are binding text and img variable?

Comment: nowhere, I don't know how to declare them

Comment: if you don't know how and where to use then how you can say my buttons still don't display me my text and image

Comment: Like this ?
`<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<tr class="btn-group" *ngFor="let button of buttonData">
  <td>
    <button onclick="onTitleClick(button)">
    {{button.title}}
      <ng-template>{{button.description}} {{button.img}}</ng-template>
  </button>
  </td>
</tr>`

Answer (score 1):

You should pass button to the function

```
  <button (click)="onTitleClick(button)">
```

and set it as

```
 onTitleClick(btnVal:any) {
    this.text = btnVal.description;
  }
```

Comment: it doesn't work, my buttons still don't display me my text and image